# Python27: Alternative of using a texfile to save variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian, raspberry-pi

I really tried to find an answer to my problem but couldn't find one, so I hope I didn't double post.

I am running a raspberry pi using debian and python27. After boot up I run a script which determines some general variables I will need for other scripts. I need this variables in different scripts because they are running during different times using crontab.
Normally after the boot up the script is done and I have all my necessary variables in a text file. 
I can access from all different other scripts to this text file. 
But know I try to avoid to corrupt my SD card of my raspberry and I want to use the read-only mode. 
Is there an opportunity to use variables which are created/changed by a python script without using a text file?
I could also run a script with an infinite loop, but I try to avoid this.

Any other suggestions? Is it possible to use environmental variables?

Thanks for every answer!

Max

Edit1:
Thanks for the suggestion the answer from adrianX, but I tried this small example and it doesn't work:

script1:

```
import os
os.environ["variable1"] = "value1"
```

After executing the script1, I run the second script.

script2:

```
import os
print os.environ.get["variable1"]
```

But this doesn't work? Maybe my question wasn't clear enough?

Comment: opps. what i suggested can't work. my bad. i'll remove my reply.

Comment: that's fine, think I wasn't clear enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non python specific solution would be: http://www.domoticz.com/wiki/Setting_up_a_RAM_drive_on_Raspberry_Pi and writing the file to the /var/tmp the file will disappear on reboot of course.

Comment: thx, that's a great idea! Did you ever tried it, I mean how much of the RAM you can use? For the beginning it should be enough.